# Cокращение вложенности объекта в Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Имеется json

```js
{
    "page_id": "123",
    "fields": {
        "desktop_content": {
            "logo": {
                "left_part": "RM / PM / ",
                "right_part": "PHOTOGRAPHY / CREATIVE CONSULTING"
            },
            "hero_content": {
                "left_block": {
                    "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/markus.ffba5_.png",
                    "name": "MARCUS RIEDER MSc./BA.",
                    "subtitle": "PHOTOGRAPHY+CONSULTING",
                    "phone_text": {
                        "left_part": "Call ",
                        "right_part": "0660/400 70 20 or"
                    },
                    "mail_text": {
                        "left_part": "Wrote to ",
                        "right_part": "marcus@local.net"
                    }
                },
                "right_block": {
                    "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/michael.35dac.png",
                    "name": "MICHAEL PELKA BSc./BA.",
                    "subtitle": "PHOTOGRAPHY+CREATIVE DIRECTION",
                    "phone_text": {
                        "left_part": "Call ",
                        "right_part": "0676/660 81 30 or"
                    },
                    "mail_text": {
                        "left_part": "Wrote to ",
                        "right_part": "michael@local.net"
                    }
                },
                "image_over_blocks": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/WeCreatePictures.png"
            },
            "we_do_block": {
                "left_block": {
                    "title": {
                        "left_part": "NOW PROUDLY WORKING WITH /",
                        "right_part": "WATERDROP"
                    },
                    "text": "Two entrepreuneurs \r\nworking together for one vision.\r\nCreate real impact for \r\nour clients."
                },
                "right_block": {
                    "icon_blocks": {
                        "icon_block1": {
                            "icon": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/icon-design.svg",
                            "title": "DESIGN"
                        },
                        "icon_block2": {
                            "icon": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/icon-photography.svg",
                            "title": "PHOTOGRAOHY"
                        },
                        "icon_block3": {
                            "icon": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/icon-consulting.svg",
                            "title": "CONSULTING"
                        },
                        "icon_block4": {
                            "icon": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/icon-strategy.svg",
                            "title": "STRATEGY"
                        }
                    },
                    "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/GoodConsistent.dec8c.png"
                }
            },
            "slider_block": [{
                    "slide_image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg",
                    "slide_title": "Warerdrop",
                    "slide_description": "HR Campaign",
                    "detailed_description": {
                        "client": "Waterdrop",
                        "year": "2017",
                        "activities": "Photography / Concept Design",
                        "overview": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Consequetur noctem tuum.",
                        "images": [{
                                "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg"
                            },
                            {
                                "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg"
                            },
                            {
                                "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg"
                            },
                            {
                                "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "slide_image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg",
                    "slide_title": "Warerdrop",
                    "slide_description": "HR Campaign",
                    "detailed_description": {
                        "client": "Waterdrop",
                        "year": "2018",
                        "activities": "Photography / Concept Design",
                        "overview": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Consequetur noctem tuum.",
                        "images": [{
                                "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg"
                            },
                            {
                                "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg"
                            },
                            {
                                "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg"
                            },
                            {
                                "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "slide_image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg",
                    "slide_title": "Warerdrop",
                    "slide_description": "HR Campaign",
                    "detailed_description": {
                        "client": "Waterdrop",
                        "year": "2019",
                        "activities": "Photography / Concept Design",
                        "overview": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Consequetur noctem tuum.",
                        "images": [{
                                "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg"
                            },
                            {
                                "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg"
                            },
                            {
                                "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg"
                            },
                            {
                                "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "blocks_with_photos": {
                "block_with_photos_left_top": {
                    "title": {
                        "left_part": "OUR SATISFIED CLIENTS / ",
                        "right_part": "CLIENT XY"
                    },
                    "photos": [{
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Client_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1-Kopie-3.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Client_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1-Kopie.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Client_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Client_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1-Kopie-12.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Client_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1-Kopie-7.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Client_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1-Kopie-8.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Client_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1-Kopie-4.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Client_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1-Kopie-11.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Client_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1-Kopie-9.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Client_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1-Kopie-13.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Client_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1-Kopie-5.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Client_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1-Kopie-14.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Client_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1-Kopie-6.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Client_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1-Kopie-2.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Client_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1-Kopie-10.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Client_Logos-11.png"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "block_with_photos_right_top": {
                    "title": {
                        "left_part": "NETWORK PARTNERS /",
                        "right_part": "CLIENT XY"
                    },
                    "photos": [{
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_PUBL_Logos-21.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_PUBL_Logos-22.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_PUBL_Logos-23.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_PUBL_Logos-25.png"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "block_with_photos_left_bottom": {
                    "title": {
                        "left_part": "COLLABORATIONS /",
                        "right_part": "CLIENT XY"
                    },
                    "photos": [{
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Collab_Logos-17.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Collab_Logos-18.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Collab_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1-Kopie-15.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "photo": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RMPM_Collab_Logos_Zeichenfläche-1-Kopie-16.png"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "image_beside_blocks": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/MakeGreatImpact.72536.png"
            },
            "get_in_touch_block": {
                "image_for_block": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/GetInTouchDesktop.png",
                "title_block": "Start the Conversation",
                "content_block": "Every beautiful Relationship starts with a simple „hello“. Let‘s make something memorable out of it",
                "text_bottom_of_block": "Or just call us now 0660/400 70 20"
            },
            "our_studio_image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/studio.7d597.jpg",
            "contact_block": {
                "left_block": {
                    "icon": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/studio-icon.svg",
                    "pre_title": "Come in and Say hi in person.",
                    "title": "Studio RM/PM",
                    "first_line_address": "Bräumühlweg 5 ",
                    "second_sub_block": "Bergheim, Austria"
                },
                "right_block": {
                    "icon": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/office-icon.svg",
                    "pre_title": "Come in and Say hi in person",
                    "title": "Office RM/PM",
                    "first_line_address": "Imbergstrasse 1",
                    "second_sub_block": "Salzburg, Austria"
                }
            },
            "social_link": [{
                    "icon": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/instagram-logo.bd840.png",
                    "link": "https://www.instagram.com"
                },
                {
                    "icon": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/facebook-logo.5322d.png",
                    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/"
                }
            ]
        },
        "mobile_content": {
            "hero_block": {
                "pre_title": "WE ARE",
                "title": "RM / PM",
                "sub_title": "PHOTOGRAPHY  DESIGN  CREATIVE CONSULTING",
                "description": "Crafting hollistic Images to  help ambitious brands grow.",
                "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/WeCreateImages.png",
                "text_bottom_of_block": {
                    "left_part": "NOW PROUDLY WORKING WITH",
                    "right_part": "WATERDROP"
                }
            },
            "slider_block": {
                "title_block": "LATEST PROJECTS",
                "slider": [{
                        "slide": {
                            "title": "Waterdrop",
                            "subtitle": "HR Campaign",
                            "link": {
                                "text": "More",
                                "url": "http://localhost"
                            },
                            "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "slide": {
                            "title": "Waterdrop",
                            "subtitle": "HR Campaign",
                            "link": {
                                "text": "More",
                                "url": "http://localhost"
                            },
                            "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cases-slide.c7ddd.jpg"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "whatwedo_block": {
                "title": "WHAT WE DO",
                "subtitle": "Two entrepreuneurs  working together for one vision. Create real impact for our clients.",
                "slider": [{
                        "slide": {
                            "image": false,
                            "title": "Design",
                            "description": "Consistent Design Expertise escorts the whole  project from start to finish."
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "slide": {
                            "image": false,
                            "title": "Design",
                            "description": "Consistent Design Expertise escorts the whole  project from start to finish."
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "slide": {
                            "image": false,
                            "title": "Design",
                            "description": "Consistent Design Expertise escorts the whole  project from start to finish."
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "slide": {
                            "image": false,
                            "title": "Design",
                            "description": "Consistent Design Expertise escorts the whole  project from start to finish."
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "brands_block": {
                "description": "We are keen on sustaining Long-Term Relationships with our Clients.",
                "images": [{
                        "image": false
                    },
                    {
                        "image": false
                    },
                    {
                        "image": false
                    },
                    {
                        "image": false
                    },
                    {
                        "image": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            "network_partners": {
                "description": "Together we are more.  Thank‘s to our relient Network Partnes we can  offer a broad range of services for our client.",
                "images": [{
                        "image": false
                    },
                    {
                        "image": false
                    },
                    {
                        "image": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            "collaborations": {
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
                "images": [{
                        "image": false
                    },
                    {
                        "image": false
                    },
                    {
                        "image": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            "get_in_touch_block": {
                "pre-title": "GET IN TOUCH",
                "title": "Start the Conversation",
                "description": "Every beautiful Relationship starts with a simple „hello“. Let‘s make something memorable  out of it",
                "text_bottom_of_block": "Or just call us now  0660/400 70 20",
                "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/GetInTouch.png"
            },
            "our_studio_block": {
                "pre-title": "OUR STUDIO",
                "image": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/studio.7d597.jpg",
                "first_sub-block": {
                    "description": "Come and play with us.",
                    "title": "Studio RM/PM",
                },
                "second_sub-block": {
                    "description": "Come and Say hi in person.",
                    "title": "Office RM/PM",
                }
            },
            "social_link": [{
                    "icon": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/instagram-logo.bd840.png",
                    "link": "https://www.instagram.com"
                },
                {
                    "icon": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/facebook-logo.5322d.png",
                    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

каким образом можно сократить вложенность? При получении этого json'a конечные свойства нужно записать в state компонента React и получается полотно цепочек.

Например:

```
fields.desktop_content.logo.left_part
fields.desktop_content.logo.right_part
```

Comment: А что должно получиться из приведенного объекта в результате этого самого сокращения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться [деструктуризацией](http://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring) и вместо длинных записей:

```
const left_part = fields.desktop_content.logo.left_part
const right_part = fields.desktop_content.logo.right_part
```

использовать следующие сокращения:

```
const { left_part, right_part } = fields.desktop_content.logo;
```

или если совсем нужно упростить

```
const {
  desktop_content: {
    logo: {
      left_part,
      right_part
    }
  }
} = fields;
```

Приведенные выше блоки равносильны по своему значению.